# FCM works with Firebase v3.4.1 but not with v5.8.1

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging

Made a new project based off of swift 3.2. and used this pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PushNotifs' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for PushNotifs
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

Now i pushed this app to my iPhone 6S for a test. and sent a message. IT WORKED.

A few minutes later made a new project based off of swift 4.0 and used this podfile:

```
 # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

    target 'Push 7' do
      # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
      use_frameworks!

      # Pods for Push 7

      # Pods for PushNotifs
       pod 'Firebase/Core'
       pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

       pod 'Firebase/Database'
       pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
       pod 'Firebase/Auth'
       pod 'GRDB.swift', '2.10.0'
       pod 'Alamofire'
       pod 'DeckTransition', '~> 2.0'
       pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.9'
       pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.5'
       pod 'SCLAlertView'

  end
```

Later did a `pod install` and got the following repsponse:

```
    Analyzing dependencies
Removing GoogleToolboxForMac
Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire (4.7.3)
Installing BoringSSL (10.0.6)
Installing Crashlytics (3.10.7)
Installing DeckTransition (2.1.0)
Installing Fabric (1.7.11)
Installing Firebase 5.8.1 (was 3.14.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 5.1.4 (was 3.7.0 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing FirebaseAuth (5.0.4)
Installing FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Installing FirebaseCore 5.1.3 (was 3.5.1 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing FirebaseDatabase (5.0.3)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (0.13.3)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID 3.2.1 (was 1.0.9 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing FirebaseMessaging 3.1.2 (was 1.2.2 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
Installing GRDB.swift (2.10.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (5.1.4)
Installing GoogleUtilities (5.3.0)
Using Protobuf (3.6.1)
Installing SCLAlertView (0.8)
Installing gRPC (1.14.0)
Installing gRPC-C++ (0.0.3)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.14.0)
Installing gRPC-ProtoRPC (1.14.0)
Installing gRPC-RxLibrary (1.14.0)
Installing leveldb-library (1.20)
Installing nanopb (0.3.8)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 11 dependencies from the Podfile and 27 total pods installed.
```

Now i'm assuming that i have firebase v5.8.1. Well. Now I can’t receive messages through FCM, message sent but not received on the device

I need help. Thank you

Comment: Please be more specific that "wont work"?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien, sorry, just updated

Comment: How are you sending the message, through the console or from a server? Are you sending a notification or a data message? Are you sending to the whole app or to a specific FCM Token? What response is received when sending the notification? Is the app in the background or foreground when trying to send the message?

Comment: @JenPerson, Just moved the issue to github: (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1867)